# Realm browser data import error and does it have relation?

Tags: swift, realm

1. How can I set relation when I input the data into realm?

   There was menu for importing on CSV or Excel files only, but for relation
   How can I make it if I need to bring it with data joined.
2. I created a db file using the realm browser and imported a xlsx file, but it did not work. What was wrong? I followed the steps below.

   1. Run the Generate Demo Database menu and created a db file in the realm browser.
   2. Opened the files made saw `realmTestClass()`, `realmtestclass1`, `realmtestclass2` files. I imported the data I made using the import menu, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The Realm Browser data importing features are still heavily in development.

If you've got any specific use cases where it is consistently crashing, or any feature requests, it would be a big help to file issues over at the [Realm Browser GitHub repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx). :)